# Material-UI select replaced by selectedValue on select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

Good day.

I am working on a piece of code in React with some Material-UI components. I currently have a Select component with MenuItem children. The Select component's options are different divs with names. What I want is to render the Select component and when a value is selected, that value's div is rendered - replacing the Select component.

Here are the Select component's options:

```
const test_options = [
    {
      name: "DIV 1",
      div: (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: 50, width: 100 }}>
          Div 1
        </div>
      ),
    },
    {
      name: "DIV 2",
      div: (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", height: 50, width: 100 }}>
          Div2
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];
```

Here is the Dropdown/Select component:

```
function Dropdown() {
    return (
      <FormControl variant="outlined">
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">
          Select a div
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
          value={test_options.name}
          key={test_options.name}
          label="Select a div"
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          {test_options.map((options) => (
            <MenuItem
              button
              key={options.name}
              value={options.name}
            >
              {options.div}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    );
  }
```

So I want a dropdown with the `options.name` as the text, and when an option is selected I want the dropdown to be replaced by the selected `options.div`. So in essence, the dropdown disappears when a value is chosen - being replaced by that value's div.

Here is all the code together:

```
import React from "react";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

export default function DropdownTest() {
  const test_options = [
    {
      name: "DIV 1",
      div: (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: 50, width: 100 }}>
          Div 1
        </div>
      ),
    },
    {
      name: "DIV 2",
      div: (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", height: 50, width: 100 }}>
          Div 2
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];

  function Dropdown() {
    return (
      <FormControl variant="outlined" style={{ width: 200 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">
          Select a div
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
          value={test_options.name}
          key={test_options.name}
          label="Select a div"
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          {test_options.map((options) => (
            <MenuItem button key={options.name} value={options.name}>
              {options.div}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    );
  }

  return <Dropdown></Dropdown>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get a solution. When an option in the dropdown is clicked, it's replaced by the selected div.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

export default function DropdownTest() {
  const test_options = [
    {
      name: "DIV 1",
      div: (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: 50, width: 100 }}>
          Div 1
        </div>
      ),
    },
    {
      name: "DIV 2",
      div: (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", height: 50, width: 100 }}>
          Div 2
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];

  function Dropdown(props) {
    const [value, setState] = useState("None"); // keep track of the current selected dropdown option
    console.log("Start value is " + value);
    const onOptionChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
      const chosen_div = test_options.findIndex(
        (obj) => obj.name === event.target.value
      );
      const value = test_options[chosen_div].div;
      console.log("Clicked value is " + value);
      ///      console.log(test_options[1].div);
      setState(value); // update state of the current selected value
    };
    if (value === "None") {
      return (
        <FormControl variant="outlined" style={{ width: 200 }}>
          <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">
            Select a div
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
            id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
            value={value} // Tell material ui select component what the current selected option is.
            label="Select a div"
            onChange={onOptionChange} // listen for on dropdown menu change
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            {props.options.map((options) => (
              <MenuItem button key={options.name} value={options.name}>
                {options.div}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      );
    } else {
      return <div>{value}</div>;
    }
  }
  return <Dropdown options={test_options}></Dropdown>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code snippet, it appears you are not watching for a change in selected option from the dropdown/Select component and you're not telling Material UI Select component what the selected value is.

```
export default function DropdownTest() {
  const test_options = [
    {
      name: "DIV 1",
      div: <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: 50, width: 100 }}>Div 1</div>
    },
    {
      name: "DIV 2",
      div: <div style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", height: 50, width: 100 }}>Div 2</div>
    }
  ]

  return <Dropdown options={test_options}></Dropdown>
}

function Dropdown(props) {
  const [value, setState] = useState("") // keep track of the current selected dropdown option
  const onOptionChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
    const value = event.target.value as string
    setState(value) // update state of the current selected value
  }
  return (
    <FormControl variant="outlined" style={{ width: 200 }}>
      <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Select a div</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
        id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
        value={value} // Tell material ui select component what the current selected option is.
        label="Select a div"
        onChange={onOptionChange} // listen for on dropdown menu change
      >
        <MenuItem value="">
          <em>None</em>
        </MenuItem>
        {props.options.map(options => (
          <MenuItem button key={options.name} value={options.name}>
            {options.div}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you macphilips for your help. I see what you're saying. 
So how do I get the selected Div to replace the dropdown on click?

Comment: Created a sandbox to show how to replace the dropdown with the selected DIV

Comment: Where can I find this sandbox?

Comment: Ah sorry I thought I added the link https://codesandbox.io/s/so-mui-select-example-ett3p?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it a lot